# Ruby regular expression function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, function

I have problem that i cant find a solution for with regular expressions, but i know it has to need it.

say i have a string inputed, say 'asdasd asdaeew asioij'
which a user makes. how would i accomplish this

```
for every word
   execute me
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions seem overkill for this one - just use

```
s = "aaaaaa bbbb cccc"
s.split.each do |w| 
  puts w
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, splitting by word boundaries instead of spaces:

```
kiss = "Keep it simple, stupid!"
kiss.scan(/\b\w+\b/) do |w|
  puts w #=> "Keep" ... "it" ... "simple" ... "stupid"
end

# Instead of:

kiss.split.each do |w|
  puts w #=> "Keep" ... "it" ... "simple," ... "stupid!"
end
```